# In oracle, create table newtable nologging parallel 4 as select * from existing table ; locks the existing table?

Tags: oracle

I am copying an existing large table with millions of rows to the same database in Oracle. Will `create table table_name as select * from existing table;` lock the existing table during the operation ?

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: If you mean by 'lock' preventing DML on the table, then the answer is No, this SQL will ot prevent you from reading or modifying the data in another session.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response

Comment: I remember , there is an sqlplus options like SET ARRAYSIZE and SET COPYCOMMIT, where we will instruct oracle to fetch a defined number of rows in a batch , and for a particular number of batch , we will give a commit. These are old commands . Is there any options in 12c , to do inserts in batches ,then commit for certain number of batches ?

Comment: Kiran, set arraysize has nothing to do with commits, it's for select. and COPYCOMMIT works only for the COPY command in SQLPLUS. Outside the copyy command, it's up to you to commit whenever you want, or set autocommit on, and in this case it will commit after each DML. Lastly, as this has nothing to do with your original question, it would have been better to ask another question.

Comment: I have already started another question . Thanks for your effort.